# How do I correct images not displaying error instead of loading correctly

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, github, windows-store-apps

The project can be found on [Github](https://github.com/SneezeWeeze/PadPedia-Windows-Store-App). It uses Visual Studio 2015. It's a Javascript Windows Store Application designed as client web app that is for the wiki found at PadPedia.org.

To replicate my issue. Download the app. Launch in Visual Studio. Type "Module" into the search box to pull up an article. You will see "X"'s where the images should be loading.

In the Javascript Console I get an error in the following format:

```
The app couldn’t resolve ms-appx://gamepaduniverse.padpedia/w/images/thumb/4/4e/Left_Arrow.png/38px-Left_Arrow.png because of this error: RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND.
```

It makes sense that the error is `RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND` because it is going to the wrong address. It should be directed to `appx://wiki.gamepaduniverse.com/w/...` not `appx://gamepaduniverse.padpedia/w/...`. I can't seem to figure out how it's pulling the data together to arrive at that result.

It has to be an issue with the file: Default.js. In that file are the only strings containing "PadPedia" and "wiki.gamepaduniverse.com"

Can someone help me isolate this issue so the images appear on the article pages.

**Update**: I placed the wrong Github link. It has been updated.

Can someone give it a look? I am not familiar with how to debug using javascript in Visual Studio.

Comment: `Download the app` two chances of that happening

Comment: The link you provided to a project on GitHub can not be found by me.

Comment: @JaromandaX link updated